# No internet even though connected to Wifi network

Tags: wireless

I am very new to Ubuntu (like yesterday!) and decided to run a dual boot of Ubuntu using the Windows installer. After some initial problems, it was installed successfully.

However, I am only connected to the internet for about two minutes time consecutively, as the WiFi connection seems to become dead then. Other devices on the same WiFi network can access the internet just fine at that time. When I'm using Windows 8 on the exact same machine, I'm also not experiencing this issue.

The internet connection on Ubuntu works for just a few minutes allowing me to open one or two web pages or to find a program in the software centre and it will then completely drop out, while the network indicator still says it's connected.

I can work around the problem a little bit by disconnecting to the WiFi manually, then reconnecting again. Yet, that only works for the same time as it will happen again after a few minutes.

The machine is a Toshiba Satelitte C850.

I would appreciate some help taking my inexperience with Ubuntu into account.

update: Ok i installed ubuntu 12.10 on a Toshiba Satellite C850 with an Intel i5-3210M and 64bit system using windows installer. Plugging in using an ethernet cable makes no difference.

Comment: Does wired connection work any better? We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: So I've found an answer...sit right next to the wifi router! Everything works fine then.

This is not much of a solution though as it's not always where i want to sit and rather negates the usefulness of having a laptop. Even moving more than 10ft away the problem returns.

Also, I work a lot in Myanmar where the internet works very differently from the rest of the world, i.e. it's very slow and as a foreigner you cannot get your own internet in your house, you have to connect to wifi hotspots or bribe a local internet cafe to stick a cable through your window.

Comment: Unless you tell us more about your hardware, we can't do much. For example, for some RAlink chips see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1749179. This may not apply if you have some other wifi chip.

Answer (score 0):

I am also very new to Ubuntu, but my experience with computer's in general has always been that wired network is far more consistent & trustworthy than wireless.

- Check if it is an error (user or software) in the browser you are using.
- Go to System Settings and look at the internet settings.
- Try connecting to various different websites.
- Run your browser with nothing else open.

That is all the help I can offer. Good luck!

Edit:

Open a terminal and try to ping an internet site eg:

```
ping www.google.com
```

This is helpful information because it will indicate whether it's a connection problem or a proxy/firewall problem.